# Modeling a 2:n relationship effectively in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

Here's the what I've got:

I have a model Match and a model Team. A Match has home_team and away_team. In fact it's a 2:n relationship.

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :home_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'home_team_id'
 has_many :away_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'away_team_id'

 public
 def matches
   return home_matches + away_matches
 end
end
```

and

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :away_team_id, :home_team_id
 belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'home_team_id'
 belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => 'Team', :foreign_key => 'away_team_id'
```

end

Effectively I can now call Team.find(2).matches and get all away and home matches. But **what I don't like is that it needs two SQL queries instead of one**:

```
SELECT `matches`.* FROM `matches` WHERE `matches`.`home_team_id` = 2
SELECT `matches`.* FROM `matches` WHERE `matches`.`away_team_id` = 2
```

How can I get Rails to use this query?

```
  SELECT `matches`.* FROM `matches` WHERE `matches`.`home_team_id` = 2 OR `matches`.`away_team_id` = 2
```

The other way around causes the same headache; If I define a method `team` that merges `home_team` and `away_team` I query the DB two times where only one query is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def matches
    Match.where("home_team_id = ? OR away_team_id = ?", id)
end
```

Also, you don't need those foreign keys in the Match model. Those attributes are contained in the Match model itself and are therefore not foreign.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The foreign keys were copy/paste errors...Anyhow, 
I was trying to be clean and use the built-in ActiveRecord relations to model that behavior. But your solution works at least in terms of the single SQL query (the most important point)... I hoped for options I can include in the belongs_to and has_many clauses. No way?